# Using Nokogiri on FedEx.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to create a small Rails application that will parse the FedEx site for my tracking information. I tried to use Nokogiri to parse the site but it seems that the content on the site is loaded via Ajax and I'm not able to capture it.

Here is the code that I was testing with:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?cntry_code=us&tab=1&tracknums=543433298736'))

doc.xpath('//*[(@id = "destinationDateTime")]').each do |status|
  puts status.content
end
```

Any help on this would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'json'

r = Mechanize.new
r.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

def fedex(r,tracking_number)

    return r.get("https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track?data={%22TrackPackagesRequest%22%3A{%22appType%22%3A%22wtrk%22%2C%22uniqueKey%22%3A%22%22%2C%22processingParameters%22%3A{%22anonymousTransaction%22%3Atrue%2C%22clientId%22%3A%22WTRK%22%2C%22returnDetailedErrors%22%3Atrue%2C%22returnLocalizedDateTime%22%3Afalse}%2C%22trackingInfoList%22%3A[{%22trackNumberInfo%22%3A{%22trackingNumber%22%3A%22#{tracking_number}%22%2C%22trackingQualifier%22%3A%22%22%2C%22trackingCarrier%22%3A%22%22}}]}}&action=trackpackages&locale=en_US&format=json&version=99").body

end

puts "Package number 543433298736 is: " + JSON.parse(fedex(r,"543433298736"))["TrackPackagesResponse"]["packageList"][0]["keyStatus"]
# For the "estimated delivery datetime": ["TrackPackagesResponse"]["packageList"][0]["displayEstDeliveryDateTime"]
```

This code get's the job done :-)

Answer (score 3):

Parsing the entire page is bad form. Use a shipping/tracking gem such as [active_shipping](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping) that utilizes the FedEx API instead. They even have a section about [tracking FedEx packages:](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping#track-a-fedex-package)

```
fedex = FedEx.new(:login => '999999999', :password => '7777777')
tracking_info = fedex.find_tracking_info('tracking-number', :carrier_code => 'fedex_ground') # Ground package

tracking_info.shipment_events.each do |event|
  puts "#{event.name} at #{event.location.city}, #{event.location.state} on #{event.time}. #{event.message}"
end
```

Comment: Nic,

I messed around with the example above and couldn't get it to do anything :-(

Comment: Did you set up a developer account with FedEx? You'll have to do that first.

Comment: +1 Using the API with or without a gem is the right way to go. Scraping their site is being a bad net-citizen when they've taken the time to create an "official" way.

Comment: Nic,

Yes sir I created a Dev account and I used the account as my log in but still no dice using the demo above.

The error that I'm getting is uninitialized constant FedEx (NameError)

Comment: Seems that I need to do this:

    # :key is your developer API key
    # :password is your API password
    # :account is your FedEx account number
    # :login is your meter number

I have test info so I'm going to try and modify the code to use the test info.

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar.. i ended up with using capybara and phantomjs via poltergeist... handles javascript quite well...

here is a part of my script:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-

require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

class MyTest

    include Capybara::DSL

    Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {debug: false})
    end

    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
    Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.example.com'

    def run
        visit('/home/bezirk?bezirk=1212')
        ...
    end
end
MyTest.new.run
```